# Generate text only when printing from web app

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of dynamic code in my web app like this:

```
<div class="hide_for_screen" id="print_page_title_block">
  <span class="small_notes">
    Printed by #session.user.first_name# #session.user.last_name# on
    #DateFormat(Now(),"long")# at #TimeFormat(Now(),"long")# System Time
  </span>
  <hr />
</div>
```

(As you can see, some of it is dynamically created server-side. It's in ColdFusion, but I don't think that matters here.)

Then in my `screen.css` I have:

```
DIV.modal_content, .hide, .hide_for_screen {
  display: none;
}
```

and in `print.css` I have:

```
.hide_for_screen{display:block;}
```

which are defined this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

All in an effort to put the "Printed by" text on a print-out of, say, a report, without having it appear if the user is viewing the app on their screen. Pretty typical, right?

The trouble comes from our new Section 508 tester. When he turns *off* CSS in his browser, he sees the "Printed by..." text and starts citing some rule that there shouldn't be any data there that's not there with CSS *on*.

So, my question is: Is there a practical way to include server-generated HTML content *only* when printing that won't appear if CSS isn't being used?

Comment: Without styles you won't be able to alternate anything (visibility included) between print & screen. In short: NO

Comment: The only thing you can do is to provide print button which will lead to html with that text, but thats nonsense, to much overhead just for simple text